# How to Find Quarters Per Different Years and Days

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Dates range per year, from 2019 - 2030

Need to categorize each date by Quarter

Quarters are:

```
11/22 - 2/21    Q1

2/22 - 5/21     Q2

5/22 - 8/21     Q3

8/22 - 11/21    Q4
```

Thought I could use a long IF function `(IF(Date >= Q1 End,1, IF(Date >= Q2 End, 2, IF(Date >= Q3 End, 3, IF(Date >= Q4 End, 4, " ")`...  This didn't work for some reason.

Then tried a **VLOOKUP** but the only way I figured it could work is if I created a lookup table that had each month within each quarter - such as:

```
11/21/2019  4

11/21/2018  4

11/21/2020  4

11/21/2021  4

11/21/2022  4

11/21/2023  4

11/21/2024  4

11/22/2018  1

11/22/2019  1

11/22/2020  1

11/22/2021  1

11/22/2022  1

11/22/2023  1

11/22/2024  1

2/21/2019   1
.....
```

This also didn't work each time.

I then tried a ROUNDUP formula with `MONTH - =ROUNDUP(IF(MONTH([@[Date]])/3+1 > 4, 1, MONTH([@[Date]])/3+1),0)`

---

This got me the best result but still wasn't exact since it didn't take the DAY cutoff (21/22) into account.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this if your days are not always the same:

```
=MATCH(A1,
   CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},
      DATE(YEAR(A1)-(A1<DATE(YEAR(A1),11,22)),11,22),
      DATE(YEAR(A1)+(A1>=DATE(YEAR(A1),11,22)),2,22),
      DATE(YEAR(A1)+(A1>=DATE(YEAR(A1),11,22)),5,22),
      DATE(YEAR(A1)+(A1>=DATE(YEAR(A1),11,22)),8,22)
    )
)
```

[image]

---

Edit:

But since yours are always on the 22<sup>nd</sup>, use this:

```
=ROUNDUP(MONTH(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+2,DAY(A1)-21))/3,0)
```

[image]

Comment: The latter one worked great, thank you!  I feel dumb asking but would you mind walking me through the logic of how this function works?  Did you figure it out using trial and error?

Comment: The second moves all the dates so `11/22` becomes `1/1` of the next year by adding 2 months and subtracting 21 days. which then the month now falls in the normal quarters.